# Simple test using a flow control choice with mule esb CE

Tags: mule, esb

I want to show a message according to the value of the variable "sent" which i take from this json file: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Rajeun/b550fe17181610f5c0f0/raw/934bf1e621d6bc056f20dee653dac74275026ba5/file.json

this is my code:

```
<flow name="cpushFlow">
    <quartz:inbound-endpoint jobName="HTTP-Puller-Scheduler" repeatInterval="3000" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="Quartz">
        <quartz:event-generator-job/>
    </quartz:inbound-endpoint>
    <https:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="gist.githubusercontent.com" port="443" path="Rajeun/b550fe17181610f5c0f0/raw/934bf1e621d6bc056f20dee653dac74275026ba5/file.json" method="GET" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.lang.Object" doc:name="JSON to Object"/>
    <choice doc:name="Choice">
        <when expression="#[message.payload.sent]">
            <logger message="c bn" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <logger message="c pas bn" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        </otherwise>
    </choice>
</flow>
```

errors:

```
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using context classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@25154f.
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@25154f class loader.
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.properties] using context classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@25154f.
log4j: Using URL [jar:file:/C:/AnypointStudio/plugins/org.mule.tooling.server.3.5.0_3.5.0.201407241708/mule/tooling/tooling-support-3.5.0.jar!/log4j.properties] for automatic log4j configuration.
log4j: Reading configuration from URL jar:file:/C:/AnypointStudio/plugins/org.mule.tooling.server.3.5.0_3.5.0.201407241708/mule/tooling/tooling-support-3.5.0.jar!/log4j.properties
log4j: Parsing for [root] with value=[INFO, console].
log4j: Level token is [INFO].
log4j: Category root set to INFO
log4j: Parsing appender named "console".
log4j: Parsing layout options for "console".
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%-5p %d [%t] %c: %m%n].
log4j: End of parsing for "console".
log4j: Parsed "console" options.
log4j: Parsing for [com.mycompany] with value=[DEBUG].
log4j: Level token is [DEBUG].
log4j: Category com.mycompany set to DEBUG
log4j: Handling log4j.additivity.com.mycompany=[null]
log4j: Parsing for [org.springframework.beans.factory] with value=[WARN].
log4j: Level token is [WARN].
log4j: Category org.springframework.beans.factory set to WARN
log4j: Handling log4j.additivity.org.springframework.beans.factory=[null]
log4j: Parsing for [org.apache] with value=[WARN].
log4j: Level token is [WARN].
log4j: Category org.apache set to WARN
log4j: Handling log4j.additivity.org.apache=[null]
log4j: Parsing for [org.mule] with value=[INFO].
log4j: Level token is [INFO].
log4j: Category org.mule set to INFO
log4j: Handling log4j.additivity.org.mule=[null]
log4j: Parsing for [org.hibernate.engine.StatefulPersistenceContext.ProxyWarnLog] with value=[ERROR].
log4j: Level token is [ERROR].
log4j: Category org.hibernate.engine.StatefulPersistenceContext.ProxyWarnLog set to ERROR
log4j: Handling log4j.additivity.org.hibernate.engine.StatefulPersistenceContext.ProxyWarnLog=[null]
log4j: Finished configuring.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Application name not specified.
    at org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer$ApplicationDeployerArguments.parse(ApplicationDeployer.java:60)
    at org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.parseArguments(ApplicationDeployer.java:48)
    at org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.main(ApplicationDeployer.java:96)
```

please can someone help me!

Comment: I've tested your application on mule 3.5.0 ce and works as expected. I think it must be something with your run configurations for this project. What happens if you run another application?

Comment: other application that i have are running in Mule EE this is my first test with the CE

Comment: There is no issue in the code .. please check you application if it contains other java valid files

Comment: wich application do you mean? and wich files?

Comment: The code looks fine to me .. I find nothing wrong in it .. just check whether there is any other issues in the application .. for example any other java files in the same application

Comment: Thank you for replying, in this example i haven't any other code, only the example that i posted.

Comment: What specific version of mule are you using? It's seems like there's something wrong with the app but not in the flow.

Comment: I'm using mule 3.5.0

Comment: Rajeun can you please create another ce application and check whether the same issue applies?

Comment: thank you for replying i have changer my anypoint studio and created the same application and it's the same probleme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a problem with the application format or Anypoint Studio version. Try creating the application again or upgrading to 3.6.0.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I had solved the error but i don't know what was the problem. I cleaned my project, updated the version of the embedded server.... I don't  know which of these solutions worked.